# What causes this error in Swift?

Tags: xcode, compiler-construction, swift, beta

I just downloaded Xcode Beta4 with the Swift language changes and updated the arrays in a piece of code (You know, Int[] to [Int]). I did not change anything else. Now my code won't compile since a really freaky error.

```
func addto(src: [Int], v: [Int]) {
    for var i = 0; i < src.count; ++i {
        src[i] = (src[i] + v[i]) % 2
    }
}
```

This causes following Error:

> '@Ivalue $T8' is not identical to 'Int'

Does anyone know what causes this error? The code should be alright.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delare `src` as `var` as parameter are constant in swift by default and you are changing the value of `src` so declare it as `var`

```
func addto(var src: [Int], v: [Int]) {
    for var i = 0; i < src.count; ++i {
        src[i] = (src[i] + v[i]) % 2
    }
}
```

You are not returning the results from function.If you want to get results in first variable as passed in function you can declare it as `inout`

`func addto(inout src: [Int], v: [Int]) {..}`

and then call

```
var abc = [1,2]
addto(&abc,[2,4]) //& is required for inout
println(abc) // will get result of function [1,0]
```

or simply return result from function

```
//Use `-> [Int]` as return type
func addto(var src: [Int], v: [Int]) -> [Int] { 
    for var i = 0; i < src.count; ++i {
        src[i] = (src[i] + v[i]) % 2
    }

    return src
}

var abc = addto([1,2],[2,4])   //abc will contains [1,0]
```

Comment: don't you mean `inout`?

Comment: no as to remove error var is sufficent but if he wants to get results it should be `inout`